# Ranking posts of all users from highest to lowest

Tags: getstream-io

if posts of users consists comments and likes and date of created, how can I implement some sort of ranking that involve number of comments and likes and date of created and returning posts from highest post to lowest.

Comment: This is in your data layer. You would add post rankings in a table and sort or group by date and user. Also, you'll find better luck here at SO by posting specific questions with code and a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Ranked Feeds](https://getstream.io/docs/#custom_ranking). Ranked feeds allows for custom ranking of activities; you can use your own formula to calculates the score of each activity. As long as your activities have the required information (eg. `likes_count`, `comments_count`) than you can use this to rank your feeds.

Here's a simple example of a ranking formula:

```
{
    "score": "likes_count + comments_count",
     "defaults": {
        "likes_count": 0,
        "comments_count": 0
    }
}
```

A very common approach is to combine some popularity score with the age of the activity. To do this you can use one of the [time decay](https://getstream.io/docs/#decay) functions and multiply the results with the sum of likes and comments.

For example:

```
{
  "functions":{
    "popularity_gauss":{
      "base":"decay_gauss",
      "scale":"5d",
      "offset":"1d",
      "decay":"0.3"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
      "likes_count": 0,
      "comments_count": 0
  },
  "score":"popularity_gauss(time) * (likes_count + comments_count)"
}
```

The example is using the `decay_gauss` function with scale, offset and decay parameters. With the chosen parameters, activities will get their score decreased as they cross the 1 day old threshold. The score will be reduced to a third for activities that are 5 days old.

**Syncing data**

The two counters that we used in the example `likes_count` and `comments_count` are clearly changing over time. For Ranked Feeds to work, you need to synchronize these values. Activity data can be updated [using the APIs](https://getstream.io/docs/#activity-update).

Note: Since the activity update API does not support partial updates, it is recommended to not update activities transactionally (eg. user clicks on like -> send API call to update counter from X to X+1) but to perform updates in bulk every X seconds.

Crontab example every 5 minutes:

```
*/5   *  *   *   *     /path/to/script/update_activities_counters
```